# Determining Jensen's Polynomial for $k$ and $k+1$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, entire-functions

Question: How can I show Jensen's Polynomial for $k$ and $k+1$ as it relates to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ if possible? I need someone to show me. 
 I just started to know about Jensen Polynomials so here is it : 
 Let $f(x)$ be a real entire function of the form 
$f(x)=$ $\sum_{k=0}^\infty$ $y_k$ ${x^k\over k!}$ 
where the $y_k$ are positive and satisfies Turan's inequalities 
for $k=1,2,...$ 
The Jensen polynomial $g(t)$ associated with $f(x)$ is then given by 
 $g_n (t)=$ $\sum_{k=0}^\infty$ ${n \choose k}$ $y_k$ $t^k$ 
where ${a \choose b}$  is a binomial coefficient 
 Here is a link to Jensen polynomial below 
 [mathworld.wolfram.com/JensenPolynomial.html][1]

[1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JensenPolynomial.html 
 Update: Here is something I am trying to see: 
 $g_1(x)=$ $\binom{1}{0}t^0 +$ $\binom{1}{1}t^1+$ $\cdots$ 
 
 where the 1st two terms are $1 + t$ and so forth if we continue this. My problem is, if I put $k$ and $k+1$ here, I do not understand fully what to do and what it will the end result be.

Comment: Please expand on your question. It is not clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I want use $k$ and $k+1$ inside the Jensen Polynomial to see what it will get me